# Finding a bounding volume (line segments) from a kDop definition.

Tags: convex-polytopes

I have a problem. 
I'm trying to recover a bounding volume (actually line segments that form the bounding volume) from a kDop definition (in a 3D space). (its to draw the kDop on screen)

In my kDOP structure i have the Min/Max values calculated for each axis. (And well, i know the axis used)

I tried before coming here 3 ways to resolve it :

1) Intersecting 3 neighboring planes to find a point and then connecting them (Sometimes the intersection is out of the k-DOP, i didn't manage to find a way to figure the correct planes to use)

2) Starting from the lines of the AABB (DOP6) and then intersecting the lines with each of the k-DOP planes, but when a line is completely behind a plane (i.e. not visible), we have to add two or more new lines and i don't know which is to be drawed and which not. :P (and i get too many lines drawed)

3) Brute force method. Intersect each plane with each other plane to get a set of lines and then intersect these lines with each plane to find the correct line segment (or discard the line) (too slow :()

What's the best way to go? Can you give some explanation on it?

Thanks

EDIT : About the slowness. Well yes, i need to do it for 100-120 objects under 16,667 ms (n^3 method takes 0,96 ms (and i've optimized pretty much everything))

EDIT 2: Answering the questions from TonyK :

1) (1,0,0)(0,1,0)(0,0,1) // AABB (Axis Aligned Bounding Box)

(1,1,1)(1,-1,1)(1,1,-1)(1,-1,-1) // Corners

(1,1,0)(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,-1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1) // Edges

These are the axes used. Are fixed and I can happen to use a subset of those. (only AABB (DOP6) or AABB + Corners (DOP14) or AABB+Corners+Edges (DOP26)). Yes, the only thing changing is the Min/Max values.
(The normals for each plane are prestored (26 normals in the worst case (DOP26)))

2) My point of view is the camera of the simulation and "can" change. (the line segment obtained will be multiplied by World/View/Projection matrix to get the final position on the Viewport, but that's a GPU detail)

3) Mhn...well, there are Axes that do not intersect each other.

4) What do you mean by "treating the bounding plane as opaque"?

EDIT 3:

Regarding the other question, No, I treat them as wireframe so the lines under the kDOP surface will appear.

Comment: Just to translate it into purely math. language. You know the N half-spaces whose intersection is a convex polytope. You want to find the edges of this polytope. The trivial $O(N^3)$ algorithm (find the intersection line of each pair of planes and see what segment other half spaces cut on this line) is, apparently, too slow. How to do it faster?

Comment: For those like me who have no idea what a kDOP is, the wikipedia page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume has a small explanation.

Comment: Now we're talking milliseconds, perhaps you can fill in some of the details. How many axes are there, and can you give a simple description of them (e.g. symmetry axes of the cube)? Are the axes fixed in space, with only their min/max values changing? Is your point of view at infinity (and is it fixed)? Do all the axes intersect each other? And you are treating the bounding planes as opaque, right?

Comment: In other words, your axes are the symmetry axes of the cube :-) (and my question about whether they all intersect was a stupid one).

By the 'bounding planes', I meant the surface of the k-DOP: if you treat them as opaque, then you only draw lines that are not obscured by the k-DOP itself (so a cube would typically require nine lines instead of twelve).

Comment: I thought a little....
Can't i simply precalculate the vertexes of the various edges manually using 3 planes as I have a limited (ALWAYS The same) number of planes/vertex to calculate?
Someone has an image with the simmetry axes of the cube? So i can take a look.
This way it should be quite faster (I just calculate the right vertex) :P

Comment: For the question, it's difficult to manage the relationship between the intersection planes.I cannot find a better way. @feal87 Have u solved this problem. I am also want to draw kdop.. Hope u can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it seems like your $N=52$ then and the normals to the planes are fixed. Then you are right that $N^3$ method takes 1ms time. Indeed, to find the parametric coefficients of the intersection of any 2 planes once you prestore the line directions and the inverse matrices takes just 6 multiplications and 3 additions, to find the cut takes 52 cycles of 6 multiplications, 5 additions, one division, and two comparisons each (keeping the max and the min), and doing all 1326 pairs that requires 1326*(9+52*14)=977262 elementary operations, which puts your processor speed at 10^9 multiplications per second, which is about right. There is an $O(N^2)$ algorithm if you know a point inside the polytope, which, once you are talking about kDop, you, probably do, but we need to count operations very carefully to see if it beats the $N^3$ one.

The key problem is that in the worst case when every plane matters, you may have about 3*52=156 edges which is just one tenth of the maximal possible amount and if you spend the same 9+52*14 operations on each edge, you will be just on the edge of what you need. Still, it is worth trying. It works under the assumption that no 4 planes intersect at one point. To make sure that it is the case, just perturb your Mins and Maxes by some random numbers that are much bigger than the precision with which you can compute the points but much less than what is visible to the eye (say, $10^{-4}$ times the object size, also make sure that you decrease Min's and increase Max's) but do all comparisons with much higher precision (like $10^{-12}$ times the object size) where  the object size is just the maximal span in your directions, which you can find in linear time.

Start with finding one edge. To this end, just take any point inside the polytope, compute the vertices of the dual polytope with respect to that point, choose any direction, and take the furthest vertex of the dual polytope from the origin. Now, you know that this plane certainly matters. It will take you just linear time, so I'll not even count that. Once you figured out one plane, you can find an edge on that plane in the time 50*(9+52*14)=36850 elementary operations just as in the $N^3$ method. Keep track on which planes give you the boundary points.

Now, at each moment, keep track of edges you already have, and the vertices you have with their planes. For each vertex also keep the track of whether you know each of the adjacent edges (according to the pair of planes) completely. In the beginning, you have the list of 2 vertices with one known and two unknown edges.

Take the first vertex in the list with at least one unknown adjacent edge. You know the pair of planes for this edge, so you can find the new edge in time (9+26*15)=737, where you have 26 instead of 52 because you can find whether you'll need Max or Min in each direction in one comparison. Once you have found the edge, see if its other end is one of the already found vertices and mark the corresponding edge at that vertex as known (about 156*2=312 operations). If not, add its other vertex to the end of the list. This gives you 1049 operations per edge.

Thus, your total is 36850+156*1049=200494 operations, which is 5 times better than my count for the $N^3$ algorithm but still a bit slower than you need.

There is a room for improvement. The most obvious one is that you may want to keep the list of already found vertices for each pair of planes (the update costs 3 operations and reduces 312 to just 6. Thus, you are down to 36850+156*153=154318, which is within the limits, but just barely. Another thing is that you can try to reduce the time you need to find the first edge. but I do not see how to do it at the moment.

---

All right, first thing first. The main part of the cure is to construct the admissibility table that, for each pair of directions, lists all directions that may form a vertex with the given two. Surprisingly, it is very short. I'll keep the directions in the 0,$\pm 1$ format like you (not normalized). I assume that you keep an array of these directions p of length 26. The only thing I want you to make sure about the order is that p[2k] and p[2k+1] are opposite for each k=0,1,...,12. This will spare a few operations in the edge tracing algorithm.

First, let us exclude all degenerate pairs. That is pretty easy. The pair (A,B) is degenerate iff A+B is a multiple of some other direction in the list. In practical terms, it means that all non-zero entries of $A+B$ are equal in absolute value. The first thing
is to create the table of pairs of directions and precompute some information for them.
To make it working for both algorithms, I suggest that for each pair (i,j) of indices, you create the structure Q[i,j] with the following fields

Boolean nondegeneracy; true if the pair is non-degenerate, false if it is degenerate.
You should get 288 non-degenerate pairs if the order of i,j matters (144 with i

vector normal; normal=$p[i]\times p[j]$ is the direction orthogonal to both p[i] and p[j]

iprojector, jprojector; those are just found as $v=p[j]\times\operatorname{normal}$; iprojector$=v/(v\cdot p[i])$ and similarly for jprojector. This will allow you to find a point X with given scalar products $a=p[i]\cdot X$ and $b=p[j]\cdot X$ as a times iprojector plus b times jprojector (6 multiplications and 3 additions)

an array goodindices of structures. Each structure element goodindices[m] will have 3 fields: integer k such that p[i],p[j],p[k] may make a vertex, and 3 scalar products iscal=iprojector$\cdot$p[k],jscal=jprojector$\cdot$p[k],and nscal=normal$\cdot$p[k]. To construct it, you take your pair a=p[i],b=p[j] of directions and include the structure with the first field k (once you know k, you can compute the other three fields) into goodindices if the following two conditions hold:

1)the determinant det=det(a,b,c) is not 0

2) for every index m different from i,j,k at least one of the determinants det(a,b,d), det(a,d,c), and det(d,b,c) where d=p[m] has sign opposite to the sine of det, i.e., if, say, det > 0, one of them is strictly less than 0 (since all coordinates are integer, compare to -0.5). This checks that there is no direction in the cone formed by a,b,c.

Funnily enough, the total number of indices in goodindices is never greater than 6.

Also, let Max[i] be the maximal scalar product of your object points with p[i]
(I prefer to keep all 26 directions and Max array to keeping 13 and Min and Max arrays just to avoid any casework anywhere)

Now, when the table is ready, it is very easy to run the N^3 algorithm. For each pair i,j with i < j do the following.

If Q[i,j].nondegeneracy=false, just skip the pair altogether

Determine tmin as the maximum over all structures S in Q[i,j].goodindices such that S.nscal<0 of the ratios (M[S.k]-M[i]S.iscal-M[j]S.jscal)/S.nscal .

Determine tmax as the minimum over all structures S in Q[i,j].goodindices such that S.nscal>0 of the ratios (M[S.k]-M[i]S.iscal-M[j]S.jscal)/S.nscal.

If tmin < tmax, put X=M[i]Q[i,j].iprojector+M[j]Q[i,j].jprojector.; compute the points X+tmin Q[i,j].normal and X+tmax Q[i,j].normal and draw the edge between them (or store it for later drawing).

You should optimize here updating tmin and tmax when looking at each k and stopping immediately if tmax gets less than or equal to tmin. This cycle over k is the most time-consuming part when defining the edge, so how you write it determines the real speed of this algorithm. Optimize as much as possible here to make sure that you do not do any extraction from array twice, etc. Each little extra operation counts and memory is not a problem. That's why I suggested to prestore the scalar products as well, though it might seem a bit silly when we are talking of cycle of length 6 within a cycle of length 144

That's all. It should run fast enough to be acceptable already and it is robust in the sense that you do not need to perturb your maxes, check for paralellness anywhere, etc., etc.

The other algorithm is still about 4 times faster but I should check that it has no stability issues before posting it. Try this first and tell me the running time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and precise explanation!!! 
It should be easy to implement having such a good guide. (I'll do it anyway even if I can find another solution just as an educational project)

A note, is it possible to do as I said in the last comment of the question and simply precalculate each vertex manually preknowing which planes to intersect (as i don't change EVER the planes) simply by doing a 3 planes intersect and linking the points one to one (it is really tedious to write every combination, but should VERY fast)

What do you think?

Comment: N is 26, I think, not 52. So fedja's method should be fast enough.

Comment: (yes its 26. 13 min and 13 max with the normals inverted)

Comment: The whole point is that despite the directions of the planes stay fixed, the vertices are not always formed by the intersections of the same triples (in a striking contrast with $\mathbb R^2$ where you just go counterclockwise) though you are right that there are some triples that have no chance to form vertex (the ones that form a cone inside which you have another direction), so you do not know the combinatorial type in advance.

Comment: But, of course, you can do the precomputation to determine for each pair of directions which other directions have any chance to make a vertex with them, which may shave some extra time off in both algorithms. Just do not do it manually: the machine can easily determine if a given vector has positive coefficients with respect to 3 other vectors and construct the table for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the suggestions fedja. Tomorrow morning i'll work on it and try to get it working fast :)

Comment: It works fine and is very fast!!! Still some problem (i get one vertices extra different only for some 0.00002 like on each elaboration. I have to find a way to discard those useless data :P) 

Comment: {X:-38.77622 Y:-0.9569161 Z:-5.700686}
{X:-38.77622 Y:-0.9569183 Z:-5.700684}

(Actually doubling the number of vertices, I'll work to find out why. :D}

Comment: Don't keep vertices as coordinates, keep them as triples of planes (integers), so you do not have any rounding errors when comparing the vertices.

Comment: Yeah, resolved in that way. Thanks.
Now i'm finding which plane to ignore it althogether to speed it up even more. (The AABB planes are useless right? I mean, even in a CUBE (no cut by the various corner/edges planes) situation the corner and edges planes are enough to find the extreme point. Or am i getting this wrong?)

Comment: The rule is the following: (I denote the unit direction vectors by capital letters) A(-A)B is useless, ABC is useless if there is D such that D=aA+bB+cC with positive a,b,c. Now, be careful. When you are doing the first randomization step, move all planes out by *the same* small random amount. Otherwise you may run into trouble when your object has sharp cones and you had 4-plane intersections in the beginning (if you do independent perturbations, the useless triple may easily become useful and everything will collapse). This also requires that your directions be generic. Can you tell them?

Comment: Mhn...taking account of the first rule (easily doable without a PC)

Taking ABC as base exclude each plane that has his own normal vector as A(-A)B

I identified at a glance :

Exclude (0,0,1) (0,0,-1) in respect of (0,1,0) (0,-1,0)
Exclude (1,-1,1) (-1,1,-1) in respect of (1,1,1) (-1,-1,-1)
Exclude (1,-1,0) (-1,1,0) in respect of (1,1,0) (-1,-1, 0)

Am i right? Or am i doing strange random things? :D
P.S. (I'm using the unnormalized vectors in this example, in the app I use them normalized obviously)

Comment: No, you do not exclude pairs. You exclude *triples*. So you exclude (1,0,0) with respect to the pair (0,1,0),(0,0,1) if you have (1,1,1) somewhere. The table should be indexed by pairs of directions and for each pair you should have the list of non-excluded directions. I'm also a bit concerned about your remark on low precision in vertex computation. It shouldn't be this way. When you find a new vertex, check the plane equations for it and see if they hold with essentially machine precision.  

Comment: I'll work to make the code to build this table when i'll be back home.
P.S. (Regarding the precision problem, actually the edges are drawed correctly (and enclose the mesh perfectly) for each test object i have (10-15 types) so the vertex "should" be calculated correctly)

Comment: The dangerous objects are degenerated ones. Try an interval object in random direction and see what the result is. If it works reasonably, everything is fine. If not, you should look into the precision issue. 

Comment: Now that i'm testing extensively the algorithm sometimes i get a number of vertices not even...(basically you can't make the last line).
Probably i'm doing something wrong...    

http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/4426/skinningdemo.jpg
http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/8758/spaceship2.jpg
http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/1092/spaceship1.jpg

These are two example of edges generated with my algorithm. The first is a skinned (vertex blend) hand animated in real time with multiple kDOP to divide its surface. The others are a spaceship static with only a SINGLE kDOP in different angulation

Comment: Do you think that the result is ok?
I actually see some strange line that goes inside the mesh. I have to try to disable Z buffering when drawing these lines to see...

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of those pictures (some of them are a bit weird and some of them are just too complicated). The number of vertices cannot be odd. Each vertex is formally a triple of planes and there is no way to saturate each vertex with an odd number of them. Run the algorithm, get the lists and do two things:

a) check that all vertices satisfy the equations of their planes.
b) check that each vertex is fully saturated (instead of pure Boolean marks, track 3 indices of adjacent vertices). 

b) should fail if the number of vertices is odd, and you'll be
able to see what's wrong.

Comment: Educated guess: you just forget to saturate the other endpoint of a newly found edge or mark it fully saturated when it isn't. Each vertex has 3 positions to saturate and I feel like you are just missing some of them. Check that you are doing each vertex completely and do not move to the next one until it is fully saturated, i.e., until all 3 positions are filled with indices of other vertices in the list.

Comment: Probably the problem is elsewhere and not in this routine. I'll investigate further and report here.
All the vertex are saturated correctly if the mesh is not in continue rotation. If the mesh is in rotation it generate odd number of vertex. (but not always, like 1 time over 10 :P)
I'll go take a look at the vertex blending/transformation routines. Something is terribly wrong. :P

Comment: mhn...basically it goes wrong depending on the rotation angle and the mesh. I'm investigating further. :P

Comment: Mhn...i tried changing the number to discard a line/point and this mesh does not goes wrongly anymore. (Other instead still are a little wrong)
I mean when i intersect plane with plane and plane with line, i test if the 2 planes are parallel by using the cross product and discard if the sum of XYZ is under a number (0.0001) actually. Same with planes vs Line, if there isn't a possible intersection (the dot product between normal of the plane and vector of the line is between -0.0001 and 0.0001) and same when testing each final point against the planes. (test if the point is behind the......

Comment: plane and then is out of the kDOP)
I don't know why, changing this value depending on the rotation of the mesh the routine fail. >.<
(Well, i'm not an expert mathematician so probably i'm doing some crazy error :D)

Comment: First of all, I need to know whether your directions are linearly independent (except trivial dependences between A and -A).

Secondly, I need to know if, when you take any 4 directions without A,-A pair in them, treat them as rows, add 1 to the end of each row, and form a 4 by 4 matrix with this rows, it is always degenerate.

If one of the answers is no, we have a problem (fixable, but irritating).

Comment: Sorry, I meant "every three of your directions are linearly independent"

Comment: Also "non-degenerate", not "degenerate"

Comment: Yes, they are linearly indipendent.
Mhn...i'm a little confused, i'll make an example so you can confirm this is the thing you want from me. (let's consider the 2 directions (0,1,0)(1,0,0)

[0,1,1]
[1,0,1]
[0,0,1]

and find the determinant to know if is degenerate (singular) or not, that is -1 in this case.
(If this is what you want then no, sometimes degenerate, sometimes not)

Comment: because for example let's take the two direction (1,1,1) and (1,0,0) and make the matrix as you said (1,1,1)(1,0,1)(1,0,1). The determinant is 0. :P

Comment: With the first one: for example take (1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1) and make the 3 by 3 determinant. It is non-zero, so you are good
Second one: take (1,0,1),(1,1,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,1) now make them into
(1,0,1;1),(1,1,1;1),(1,0,0;1),(0,1,1;1) Take the 4 by 4 determinant. If it is non-zero, you are good. I'm going to teach my class now. Will be back in an hour.

Comment: Ok, good work. See you in an hour.

Anyway tested with (1,0,1)(1,1,1)(1,0,0)(1,1,0) (four possible direction) maked them into [1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,1], the determinant is 0 and the matrix is singular (degenerate).

Comment: You mean, those are your real directions? Can you tell me all 13 then? I need to look at them to suggest a good and quick fix. If you have degeneracies like that, the algorithm as I described it is destined to have some issues. 

Comment: the one i posted above are the axis used (1,0,0)(0,1,0)(0,0,1) //AABB (Axis Aligned Bounding Box) (1,1,1)(1,-1,1)(1,1,-1)(1,-1,-1) // Corners (1,1,0)(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,-1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1) // Edges obviously the other 13 with inverse sign (26 normal in total)

Comment: wait those are non normalized, if normalized probably nobody degenerate. :P

Comment: Anyway as i further tested in the simulation. If i disable the draw of the edges when the number is odd (before draw i check), in the rest of the times the edges are drawn perfectly. So its probably some vertex that's falling somewhere causing the whole lines to slip (as the renderer pick the vertex in order, if one is missing, all goes crazy)

Comment: I think i'll try to redo the algorithm implementation from scratch tomorrow. :P

Comment: Ah, I see. (1,0,0),(0,1,0),and (1,1,0) are linearly dependent and so are many other triples, which screws everything up rather thoroughly in some cases. I'll try to think of some good and quick fix. No need to redo everything yet. By the way, are those directions sacred or you can change them to whatever you want?

Comment: Can change to whatever i want. 
The directions/axes/planes are the means for me to deliminate a complex mesh/object inside a kDOP for more precise collision detection while maintaining the speed of intersection check of a Axis Aligned Bounded Box (from which the kDot pick the features (and is almost the same speed to intesect)). In fact a kDOT can be an Axis aligned Bounded Box if the planes used are only the first 3. (1,0,0)(0,1,0)(1,1,0)
Every plane would work actually even (142,102,841) (Numbers picked randomly). 

Comment: That also explains the duplication of vertices effect. It was, actually, a real thing, and a good one at that. You may really have such close pairs of vertices and should keep them. Perhaps, it is not so nice for drawing, but you can easily identify such pairs in the very end and discard them before producing the picture. I'll post the way I would do everything tomorrow (and try to run a few experiments myself). 

Comment: (Generally we use planes in the +1/0/-1 range because its faster to calculate in real time the Min/Max values (absolutely no need for multiplication, just addition and substraction))
This is important as in a scene can appear 300-400 kDot objects that needs updated (and then regenerated the kDOT) for 60 times a second.
The draw of the edges of the kDot (what are we trying to do) are needed for modelist that needs to create complex hierarchy structure of kDot to deliminate more complex mesh/objects and give realistic feel to the collision. 

Comment: (without a visual aid, they don't know if the vertex they chooe to assign a kDot to make a good fit or not)
I have to ask you a big favor in the meantime we find a solution for this problem. Can you tell me the steps to the N^3 solution so I can rebuild it for the modelist to work on while I can play on optimizing and learning a more advanced algorithm? (the one we are working to :D) 

(cause i deleted the code and I don't really remember all the steps i picked up to make it work in the past days xD)

As far i remember

Comment: 
1) Pick all the planes (Min and Max) for a total of 26 planes
2) Intersect each plane with each other (NPlane * (NPlane-1) / 2) lines generated.
3) For each line, intersect with each planes and get a series of points.
4) For each point, check if it is part of the kDOP
at this point I don't remember how I managed to get all the point linked together.

Comment: Ok, i'll wait for your post tomorrow. :)
I'm actually thrilled, its fun to work on these things even if they aren't actually my field of work (i'm a 3D developer, but not really a mathematician :D)

Comment: (in the first post there is a ditto. the axis of the AABB are (1,0,0)(0,1,0)(0,0,1). I typed them wrongly)

Comment: N^3: Intersect each pair of planes, get a line, find the interval on the line cut by all other half-spaces (if the line is parameterized as $x+mt$ where x is some point on the line and m is the direction, each half-space gives either an upper or a lower bound for t); if it is non-empty (the least upper bound for t is greater than the largest lower bound), find the endpoints and keep it as an edge to draw. Otherwise go to the next pair. 

Comment: Ok, i found out the problem in the N^3 code i was reproducing again. At least now I have a working implementation, now let's work tomorrow to get the other working too. :D 
The N^3 code was not working cause I was searching not only the lower/upper bound of each segment, but every point possible. (I wrongly thought that the maximum number i can find of them is two, but that's wrong :P) In most case are only two, but in some case more causing the problem. :D

Anyway I can give a confirmation, Yes, even in the N^3 implementation i get some segment long 0.00003, so your guess was correct.

Comment: Now I have a question for the N^3 case for when you will be back tomorrow. (probably will be useful for the N^2 too)
When i process each line against the planes to obtain the points of the segments, sometimes i get ODD number of points. In this situation what should i do? Actually I discard the extra point (in the mesh drawed 1-2 lines disappear for these frames (not a big problem for the result i want, but i'm interested on why it happens, and how to resolve)).

Comment: I tried to make a line from the minimum point found to the odd point and every line seems to be working now (at least in the sample). Well i don't know why :D

Comment: OK, I edited my post to describe the optimal N^3 realization. It should be very easy to implement. I want to know the running time of this version.

Comment: I just started to implement your optimized N^3 implementation and I have some doubts in the table. (almost completely implemented). Correct me if these assertion are false. 1) The pair (A,B) is DEGENERATE if EVERY absolute value of non-zero element (x,y,z) of the sum A+B are equal. 2) the matrix 3x3 that we need to check the determinants is [A.x,A.y,A.z][B.x,B.y,B.z][C.x,C.y,C.z]. (i mean  each vector is a row and not a column) 3) I can safely cache this table to reuse in different executions of the algorithm (changing only the Distance values of the planes (Min/Max basically))

Comment: My code find only 94 nondegenerate pairs... (following what i said just above)
The check for the determinant fails too. (it doesn't find any good indices) Here's what i'm doing :
for each i,j pair, check all the k different from i,j and if the determinant of (p[i],p[j],p[k]) is different from 0, do for EVERY m different from i,j,k the check for the determinant of (p[i],p[j],p[m]) (p[i],p[m],p[k]) (p[m],p[j],p[k]). If at least one of these 3 is of sign inverse to the first determinant. (if the first det is positive, one of the three det must be negative). 

Comment: If one these check on m fails, k is skipped.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Does not matter, the determinant of the transpose is the same as the determinant of the matrix 3) Of course, that's the whole point.

Now one thing: everything will work perfectly is your Maxes are true maxima of the scalar products with directions over the object (or some dense set of points in it). Otherwise we cannot guarantee that the vertex formed by three directions will be cut off by the plane corresponding to the direction in their cone and the whole table thing will fail dramatically.

Comment: Yes, if the test fails for just one m, k is skipped.

Comment: My maxes (and mins) are calculated doing ||||| Value = Vertex.X + Vertex.Y - Vertex.Z; ||||| (that is an example for the direction (1,1,-1)) and picking up the max/min value. (going through ALL the vertex in the object)

Comment: I implemented this table yesterday on my PC and it worked fine. Let's start with non-degenerate pairs. You should consider all 26 directions. You should find $C=A+B$ take the absolute value of every non-zero element of C and check that some two of them are not equal to claim that the pair is nondegenerate. So, if (1,1,1),(1,-1,0) is nondegenerate (2 in the first position, 1 in the third for the sum) but (1,1,1),(-1,-1,0) is not. Find all 144, and then we'll talk about the det check.  

Comment: Yes, with these Maxs and Mins it should work fine.

Comment: ok, I was making a stupid error. (i was processing from (i/j=0 to planeslength/2) instead of from (i=0 to planeslength) and (j=i+1 to planeslength))
Now i have 144 nondegenerate pair.
Let's go the the determinants. :D

Comment: Just to convince you that they are 144. Each 3 ones element (8 of those), say, (1,1,1), makes a nondegenerate pair with each 2 one element except (-1,-1,0),(0,-1,-1), and (0,-1,-1) (9 of those) and each 1 one element with +1 in it (3 of those), giving you 8*12 pairs
(which is already greater than your 94). Each 2 one element (1,1,0) makes a non-degenerate pair with 4 2 one elements (1,0,1),(1,0,-1),(0,1,1), (0,1,-1) so we have 12*4/2=12*2 such pairs and 2 1 one elements (1,0,0) and (0,1,0), so 12*2 more pairs. Now 12*(8+2+2)=144 

Comment: (I was sure it was a problem with my code, our difference in experience with mathematics is really evident i think ATM. :P)

Comment: Ok, determinants. Take i,j. Take k If det=det(p[i],p[j],p[k])=0, skip k.
Now take all m different from i,j,k (check that you indeed never take m equal to one of them and that you didn't put (0,0,0) somewhere in the array p; those were MY error yesterday). Test that at least one determinant det(p[m],p[j],p[k]),det(p[i],p[m],p[k]),det(p[i],p[j],p[m]) has an opposite sign to the sign of det. If it is true, go to the next m. If it is false, break the m loop and skip k.
An instance of good vector for the pair (1,1,1),(1,1,0) is (0,1,-1). See where you lose it in your code. 

Comment: I was calculating wrongly the determinant. Now i get 576 good indices. These values are the same as for you? If yes i'll start with the final part of the code.

Comment: Yes, if you count only i<j.

Comment: I don't understand the last part in fact. I have two question :

1) How to calculate iProjector (i've done CrossProduct(Table[i][j].Normal, Planes[i].Normal), but i'm not sure its the right way);
2) The tMin and tMax part, to me it seems that NEVER the condition will be true as you said to calculate tMin as the Maximum of an expression and tMax as the minimum of the SAME expression...
Probably i'm getting something wrong...

Comment: Another question. as M you intend the array with the Min/Max values right? (I have them in the order 0...(K/2-1) <--Min (K/2)...K-1 <--Max)

Comment: iProjector: Almost. I had a misprint there. It should really be Planes[j].Normal. Terribly sorry for that. Then you get what I called v. It has the right direction but wrong length. You should now divide v by its scalar product with p[i]. For jProjector just reverse the roles of i and j.

M: Yes, but I want all inequalities for the object vertices x to be of the form x$\cdot$p[i] < M[i], so the inequality x$\cdot$p[i] > Min[i] becomes x$\cdot$(-p[i]) < -Min[i] and should be associated with the vector -p[i], which has some other index. As I said, I do not want any casework in the main loop. 

Comment: 2) Damn, one more stupid typo! The expression is the same but you should take the maximum over the entries with nscal<0 fot tmin and the minimum over the entries with nscal>0 for tmax. Those are two disjoint sets!

Comment: Ah that was the reason it was never Min < Max. XD

Comment: Ok, now it generate lines (totally wrong, but hey its a progress). As a sidenote, actually this algorithm take 0.04 ms so we are on the right track. :D
Another series of questions. 1) "Single Value = (M[S.K] - M[i] * S.iScal - M[j] * S.jScal) / S.nScal;" for generating the Min/Max values is correct? 2) iScal = DotProduct(_table[i][j].iProjector, Planes[k].Normal); <--its right? 3) X = M[i] * Table[i][j].iProjector + M[j] * Table[i][j].jProjector; is right to calculate the X in the final part?


Comment: No reason to answer, i found out the problem. It was because i used Min instead of -Min. Now it works FLAWLESS!!! Fantastic. :D
Now i'll go do 2-3 benchmark and screenshots for you :D

Comment: 1,2,3 - yes. Now, since the lines are wrong, check a few things.

a) If you compute X as in 3, and take its scalar products with p[i],p[j],and p[i]$\times$p[j] you should get M[i],M[j], and 0. If you are not getting that, iProjector and jProjector are incorrect. If you are getting that, those are fine.

b) If you take Y=X+SingleValue*Table[i][j].Normal, this point Y should lie on the plane Y$\cdot$p[S.k]=M[S.k]. If it's wrong, you have incorrect SingleValue.

Confirm if these two tests work.

Comment: First Execution (create table) : 19 ms ||| Other executions : going from 0.03640 to 0.05750 ms ||| http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/3030/worksxi.jpg <--example (it works on all 34 test object i have) ||| http://pastebin.com/m7341fe2a <--here's the code for any people who is having the same problem. :)

Comment: A lot of thanks fedja for all the patience to take me through all this ordeal. I doubt i would ever do anything without your help. :)
Thanks!!!

Comment: I'll try to see if I can make the main loop better. One improvement is obvious: the inner loop in j should go up to i-1, not up to 25 (50% reduction in time). Stay tuned for more!

Comment: Mhn...I'm investigating on why the same code does not work properly with DOP14 (the first 7 planes).

Comment: (obviously the code is adapted to generate a 14x14 table)

Comment: Basically the code miss all the connecting lines. http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/7236/wrongdop14.png

Comment: (the old slow code takes 0.11 ms with DOP14 so tecnically i can leave that alone, but it would be nice to understand why its failing)

Comment: Because the table for DOP14 should be completely different. In particular, the rule for degenerate pairs is no longer the same. The general rule (for 0-1 vectors) is that the pair is degenerate if A+B is a multiple of some vector C in your set. It reduces to the simple rule I told you for the full set, but not for its proper subsets. As long as everything is symmetric and 0-1, you can just call A,B degenerate if Crossproduct(A+B,C)=0 for some C in the set (C can be taken A or B here). If you correct this step, it should work for DOP14 too. 

Comment: Yes they are symmetric and the axis will be always those. I'll try right away :D

Comment: Yes works fine now on both DOP14 and DOP26.

DOP14 : 0.01340 min 0.01850 max
DOP26 : 0.03420 min 0.03930 max

after i've corrected the loop as you said.

Comment: Should we try to shave some more time off or it is already what you were looking for? Since 0.04*200=8 < 16, I think the job is done and we deserve some rest now but we can try the other algorithm later just for the fun of it if we both have time. One more thing: try www.artofproblemsolving.com computer science and informatics subforum next time. I go there too. MO is, striclty speaking, not for such discussions (though I liked working with you :lol:)

Comment: ok, i'll register right away. Yeah, i think the same. :D 
Let's rest for a while, I have the brain on fire ATM. Too much math is bad for health. :D

Answer (score 1):

may I know the order of your planes? when I change the order of the planes, the lines that are drawn changes as well

Comment: when you create the admissibility table, the order of normal for that table must correspond to the order of normal for the KDOP that is used to compute the min/max values?